# Recommendation for web-based database visualization tool

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, dataset, visualization

[Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/) is extremely flexible when it comes to visualizing and playing around with datasets, but it is extremely slow when you go into "production mode" and publish a particular view that you've created onto your server. Does anyone know of any tools that can be used to connect to a database, present interactive (or somewhat interactive) dashboards, and perform reasonably well when published to a server? To be clearer, I am looking for something like this -- http://www.corda.com/executive-dashboard-graph-styles.php.

I realize that such a product might not exist. If so, is there a particular framework or library that I could use to create killer interactive visualizations of data for the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html

This demo looks like what I am after: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html

Answer (score 1):

This one from datadynamics looks very much like tableau
[link](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/DDA/Overview.aspx)
You have to make it fast yourself since it's more a component then a complete product.. 
Also, it is not as beautiful/snappy as tableau

Cliqview is an enterprise solution.
[link](http://www.clickview.com/)
Very expensive but great to build dashboards. And also very fast "out of the box"

Answer (score 0):

You could check out our visualization software. We have both free and commercial versions at http://www.inetsoft.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

Tableau has a new release, version 6, that provides a major improvement in performance. Its available to current users in beta (Sept 2010), and they've announced plans to release it by early Dec 2010. Based on the stability I've seen of the beta, they'll easily make their release date. The performance gains are substantial. It flies.

Full disclosure. I've been a customer since version 1. Our company has been a Tableau partner in past years, but currently we have no financial ties to Tableau. Just a happy user.

Update: version 7 is now released that's even better: http://www.tableausoftware.com